# How can I configure the login screen to be displayed in portrait orientation?

Tags: login, lightdm, appearance, orientation

I just started using linux, and I have one question. I have a monitor that I rotated 90◦ clockwise, so it, being rectangle shaped, is taller than it is wider.

Using the system settings in Ubuntu, I set it up, and it works great, except the login screen and loading screen are not rotated right. They are rotated in the "normal" way. Is this just a glitch, or is there some setting I overlooked? I am using the open source drivers, and it is an ATI card, if that matters.

Comment: what ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: I think you will want to use xrandr to rotate the screen, `xrandr -o right` , but the location to put that command varies with version of Ubuntu and what greeter you use (gdm, lightdm, kdm, slim, etc).

Answer (score 1):

When I boot my computer, the graphics look different than when I am logged in (not using open source nvidia driver)... so I am guessing it might be that you need to set your computer to boot with those options.  It sounds like you set your Desktop environment (Unity/Gnome/Xfce/KDE, whatever you use) to display your desktop rotated.  So, I think you need some thing to boot your machine in sideways mode.  I can't give you a solution, HOWEVER, I can point you to ubuntuforums.org (where there is a lot of ubugurus hanging out), and possible check out the GRUB2 documentation (assuming you are using a more recent version of Ubuntu since you are new to it...)  GRUB2 documentaion https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2.  I hope this helps you, and bumps your page for more attention