# (How) Can X11 Know My Screen Orientation Pre-Login? (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, login, lightdm, xrandr

Problem: a laptop usually plugged into 2 external monitors, both rotated 90 degrees.

At login time, the 3 displays are mirrored, and only the laptop itself is appropriately oriented. I'd prefer to have the laptop screen closed, and be able to see what I'm typing/control my mouse naturally during login.

I'd also prefer all desktop environments, and all user accounts to automatically get the same monitor configuration, not to have to set it individually within each account (and presumably each windowing environment).

On the other hand, if the laptop isn't docked, or is plugged into a projector, I'd like to have a sane appearing screen, based on hardware detected - and have this once again apply even at the login screen.

Is this even possible? If so, how do I do it?

While I'm looking for the general answer, in this case I don't have proprietary graphics drivers or the cards that require them.

Window managers potentially involved: just about anything. I presently have kde and fluxbox installed, but that's subject to change. Happy to read answers like "this will work in my-fav-window-manager; here's how" even if I'm not currently running it.

I consider my level of cluefulness about X11 to be very low; general linux cluefulness fairly high. I.e. please don't assume too many X related clues when replying ;-)

The following earlier question leaves me thinking the task is doable, but doesn't tell me how:
[How can I configure the login screen to be displayed in portrait orientation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95763/how-can-i-configure-the-login-screen-to-be-displayed-in-portrait-orientation)